# prove by induction that for all n in N the number $3^{2n} - 1$ is divisble by 8

Tags: real-analysis

I have the work of the proof done, but at the end after showing
$3^{2(n+1)} - 1=9(3^{2n} - 1)+8$
I make the statement that since $9(3^{2n} - 1)$ is a multiple of 8 and 8 is a multiple of 8 then $3^{2n} - 1$ is a multiple of 8. I need to quote the facts about divisibility I use in this statement and I'm not sure exactly what to put for that, I have already included the definition of divisibility in the proof

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a detail, you're assuming $3^{2n}-1$ is a divisible by $8$, so it equals $8w$ for some integer $w$.  Then your last expression is

$$9(3^{2n}-1)+8 = 9(8w)+8 = 8(9w+1),$$

which is a multiple of $8$.

Answer (score 0):

Induction hypothesis: $$8\mid 9^n-1$$so $$ 8\mid 9(9^n-1) = 9^{n+1}-9$$

but then $$8\mid (9^{n+1}-9) +8 = 9^{n+1}-1$$